# I am having trouble forwarding data from servlet to my jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am new to the servlet and jsp scene and was having trouble with getting my data from my servlet out to my jsp. I followed examples i found online and have done everything i know how to do in order to get data to my jsp.

Here is the code that i have for my servlet. I tried to pull all the data from the database and then forward that to jsp.

Another problem i had was that if i try to print any of the info to the console with system.out nothing shows.

I commented some stuff out to try and eliminate possible problem areas.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
try
    {
    String query = "select * from PRODUCT_TABLE";
    // connect to DB
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("took this out for security");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    // get info from DB 
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next())
        {
         // itemName = rs.getString("ITEM_NAME");
          itemNum = rs.getString("ITEM_NUM");
          itemPrice = rs.getString("ITEM_PRICE");
          // compile all the data
          /*itemNameComp[i] = itemName;
          itemNumComp[i] = itemNum;
          itemPriceComp[i] = itemPrice;
          i++;*/
        }

    req.setAttribute("itemName", 567);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/StartShopping.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    //String test = req.getParameter("itemName");

    //rd.forward(req, resp);

    //store info in the session object

    // get selection from user and do calculation for total purchase

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in the code below i tried to hard code some value to try and see if i could at least get something to the jsp even if it wasnt from the data that i wanted.

```
req.setAttribute("itemName", 567);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/StartShopping.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

The code that i used to call the hard set data in the JSP is below

```
<%=(String)request.getAttribute("itemName")%>
```

The code above prints "null" in the .jsp. i wanted to try and make it print just as a test to see if i could force it to work with hard data.

i tried changing it to req.getAttribute but the jsp wasnt happy with it

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!!! i apologize if there is some obvious error but i can't find it.

Comment: Post the jsp by which you are calling this servlet ans servlet class code And your web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to just run the jsp file?

In that case the attribute is never forwarded from the servlet and the jsp page always prints null.

try to create a html file which invokes the post method in servlet:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/yourServletURL" method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh ahh i see, ok, thank you very much that caused to to reprint the data that i wanted.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

May be because your are setting an integer and trying to typecast it to String
Use the following code and check once

```
 req.setAttribute("itemName", "567");
 //instead of  req.setAttribute("itemName", 567);
```